# Rewritten QLabel class seems wrong in PyQt5

Tags: pyqt5, qlabel

I rewrite the QLabel class to select ROI on the QLabel, aimed to acheive the cv2.selectROI function. But still wrong......

This is the code:

**The QMainWindows Code:**

```
class MyGui(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyGui, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_rect = [0, 0, 0, 0]
        self.tracker = None
        self.first_frame = True
        self.video_name = r'G:\dataset\example_Trim.mp4'
        self.setupUi()
        self.cap = None
        self.status = self.statusBar()  # 实例化创建状态栏
        self.status.showMessage('Author', 10000)  # 显示状态栏信息
        self.timer_camera = QTimer()

        self.show_windows = roiLabel()
        self.show_windows.setFixedSize(1500, 800)
        self.show_windows.move(50, 10)
        self.show_windows.setStyleSheet("QLabel{background-color:gray;}")

    def setupUi(self):
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.setFixedSize(1600, 900)  # 设置窗口的大小
        self.setWindowFlag(QtCore.Qt.WindowMinimizeButtonHint)  # 去掉最小化按钮
        self.setWindowTitle('基于Transformer的视频目标跟踪方法研究')  # 设置窗口标题
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r'F:\PythonDoc\trans_tt_backup\gui\pic\Windows_icon.png'))  # 设置图标
        self.move_center()
```

**And the rewritten QLabel class is :**

```
class roiLabel(QLabel):  # 利用QLabel绘制ROI
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.open_keyboard_flag = False
        self.open_mouse_flag = False
        self.draw_roi_flag = False
        self.select_roi_flag = False
        self.clear_flag = False
        self.x0 = 0
        self.y0 = 0
        self.x1 = 0
        self.y1 = 0
        self.rect = QRect()
        self.label_show = None

    # 按下鼠标时，记录左上角坐标
    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if self.open_mouse_flag is True:
            self.select_roi_flag = True
            self.x0 = event.x()
            self.y0 = event.y()
```

*The problem is:*
[image]

*I want the 'python' windows is embed in mainwindows*
[image]

Comment: `self` is passed implicitly in Python methods, so you need not and should not pass it explicitly.  i.e. don't call `roiLabel(self)`, call `roiLabel()` and rely on the Python runtime to pass the appropriate `self` argument into roiLabel.__init__(self) for you.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner it seems like the OP wants to set the *parent* widget for the constructor. The problem is that their subclass doesn't support the argument.

Comment: @JiaqiLee change to `def __init__(self, parent=None):` and `super.__init__(parent)`. Also, please post code as *text*, not images.

Comment: @musicamante @Jeremy. i follow your advice and thank you. i change to `def __init__(self, parent=None):` and `super.__init__(parent)` and `roiLabel()`. But there comes an unexpected problem: i want this _windows_ doesn't pop out. Because when i use the origin **QLabel**, the video is embed in the mainwindows, how to solve this problem? Forgive my English is poor! _the picture is above_

Comment: @JiaqiLee `self.setCentralWidget(self.show_windows)`. By the way, if you remove the `self` argument, the whole `parent` modifications I suggested become pointless.